# How to design a good QuickBooks integration solution

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I have now played with the QBO and QBD APIs and feel I have a fair understanding of how it thinks and how to interact with it.  So now it is time to design the actual integration solution.

Inside my application you can create new customers, quote services, perform services, and soon, pass invoices to QuickBooks, sounds easy.

But what if the customer is not in QB yet?  No problem - for each invoice I will look up the customer (need the id anyway) and if it doesn’t exist, add it.   But if I have to look up the customer for each invoice it seems like it might be slow.  I will likely have 30,000 customers and have 500-3000 invoices per day.

So my question is this; what are others doing?

a) Are you storing the QB id for each customer in your data?

b) How do you detect address changes (changed in your app and changed in QB)?

c) Is the batch submission interface so much faster I should use that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

We often times do store the QB id in our database for use. If we post an invoice into QB, we'll then store the QB id for future use if we need to modify it.

As far as detecting changes on the customer record and other info, there's a couple ways to handle the conflict resolution. One is to keep a timestamp on your side as to when changes are made. You can then compare this with the timestamp of the last change on the QB record and then make your decision as to which one gets updated.

Comment: This is essentially how we do it as well.

Answer (score 1):

FreddyMac,
To detect changes on the Intuit side you can construct a query with a CDCasOf Filter, which will return only the data that has changed since a date you provide. (ChangeDataCapture as of)

https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0100_Calling_Data_Services/0015_Retrieving_Objects

You need to keep track of data changes on your side.

The batch submission is not faster, its just easier for you to write the code.
The IPP SDK can queue the API calls for your and aggregate the responses.

regards,
Jarred